# Best way of maintaining a connection to a remote service for a hardware device?

Tags: websocket, raspberry-pi

This is a bit of an awkward question, but here goes.

I'm trying to build a door unlocking system using a Raspberry Pi. I want the Pi to maintain an open connection to a remote server, such that I can test presence (i.e. is the Pi alive), and send it commands. I want to also mitigate typical household router NAT & Dynamic IP issues.

My question is this: what protocol is most suited for this?

What I was thinking was to use something like web sockets, that would allow me to connect to a service like Pusher or my own server. The problem with this is that I'll be doing it from straight Python, so there is no web-browser in-between. I'm not sure what other options I have, if any.

Apologies for the open ended nature of this question, but I wasn't sure where else to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A real-time network would be a great medium for relaying data between your Raspberry Pi and a remote server (or any number of remote devices.) I listened to [Gordon Hollingworth](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/tag/gordon-hollingworth) give [a talk at API Strategy Conference about his educational strategy with the Raspberry Pi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhOa8UsvxDs), and I have been playing around with one since then. Here's what I've learned.

First, since Pi runs **linux**, you can code in any language you like. The realtime network I'm most familiar with, **PubNub**, has [SDKs in something like 50 languages](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/). In particular, using the [**PubNub Python SDK**](https://github.com/pubnub/python), you can subscribe to events with this code block:

```
pubnub = Pubnub(
    "demo",  ## PUBLISH_KEY
    "demo",  ## SUBSCRIBE_KEY
    None,    ## SECRET_KEY
    False    ## SSL_ON?
)

def receive(message) :
    print(message)
    return True

pubnub.subscribe({
    'channel'  : 'hello_world',
    'callback' : receive 
})
```

To send a message, now that you've defined your `pubnub` variable, you would simply use:

```
info = pubnub.publish({
    'channel' : 'hello_world',
    'message' : {
        'some_text' : 'Hello my World'
    }
})
print(info)
```

This SDK is quite lightweight and easy to implement (and PubNub is [free for up to 1m messages per month](http://www.pubnub.com/pricing/).)

Since you asked about different protocols, I may as well mention that if you'd like to work with even lower-level services, you can send **TCP packets** [directly to the PubNub interface using the instructions in this gist](https://gist.github.com/stephenlb/9496723#file-pubnub-http-streaming-md). Briefly,

```
telnet pubsub.pubnub.com 80

GET /stream/demo/a/0/10000 HTTP/1.1
Host: pubsub.pubnub.com
```

This will obviously help to decrease power consumption compared to using the SDK or a WebSocket solution.

On the other hand, since you are familiar with Python and WebSockets, you can always **roll your own solution**. Heroku has [a post about spinning up a chat server using Python WebSockets on their blog](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-websockets) using async callbacks and **Redis**. Here's an example of the code that syndicates messages to different clients:

```
def run(self):
    """Listens for new messages in Redis, and sends them to clients."""
    for data in self.__iter_data():
        for client in self.clients:
            gevent.spawn(self.send, client, data)
```

Good luck, let me know how it goes!

Comment: Oh wow. What a fantastic answer! Thanks so much! This has given me a lot to look into! Thank-you! :)